# Communicating ESP32 with Arduino IDE via MQTT to Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, mqtt, esp32

I am working on the ESP32 with a DHT 11 sensor where my goal is to send data over from the ESP32 via WiFi locally to the Raspberry Pi through Node Red. The Node Red is acting as the server broker for my data but I am unable to connect the ESP32 to Node-Red.

Does anyone has any suggestion or ideas on how I am able to solve this?

Below is the code i used for Arduino that is running on the ESP32.

```
    #include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>

// Wi-Fi credentials
const char* ssid = "hkst2023";
const char* password = "BEftsp2023#";

// MQTT broker configuration
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.100";  // Replace with your Raspberry Pi's IP address
const int  mqtt_port = 1883;
const char *topic = "testing";
const char* mqtt_username = "mqtt123";          // MQTT username, if required
const char* mqtt_password = "00000000";          // MQTT password, if required

// DHT sensor configuration
#define DHTPIN 5              // DHT11 data pin (GPIO2 on ESP32)
#define DHTTYPE DHT11         // DHT sensor type

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

// Initialize MQTT client
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
  // Start DHT sensor
  dht.begin();

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi. IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Connect to MQTT broker
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);
  // If your MQTT broker requires authentication:
  // client.setCredentials(mqtt_username, mqtt_password);
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  // Read temperature and humidity from DHT sensor
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();

  // Check if the reading was successful
  if (isnan(humidity) || isnan(temperature)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    delay(2000);
    return;
  }

  // Publish data to MQTT topics
  char tempStr[6];
  char humStr[6];
  dtostrf(temperature, 2, 2, tempStr);
  dtostrf(humidity, 2, 2, humStr);

  // MQTT topics for temperature and humidity
  const char* tempTopic = "esp32/temperature";
  const char* humTopic = "esp32/humidity";

  client.publish(tempTopic, tempStr);
  client.publish(humTopic, humStr);

  delay(5000);  // Delay for 5 seconds before the next reading
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESP32Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else { 
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: The Flow from node red]
[image: The MQTT settings]
[image: Server Broker information in Node Red]

Comment: Node-RED is not a MQTT broker, you will need to install/run a separate broker.

Answer (score -1):

you have to install some sort of mqtt broker (like Mosquitto) on your raspberry pi then you will get your desired results.